# Вынесение DAL в отдельный проект

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Сейчас пытаюсь разделить проект на DAL и WebUI/BLL.
Как быть с MetadataType и ресурсами для [Display], если я хочу файлы с ресурсами оставить в WebUI/BLL то и Metadata надо оставлять? если оставлять то возникает много ошибок с описанием одного класса в двух пространствах имен.
Хотелось бы посмотреть на пример проекта с отдельным DAL и описанием метаданных, ресурсов.

UPD:
Задача: Model и DataAnnotations в разных пространствах имен, возможно как-то сделать что бы partial класс с MetadataType объединились с классами в Model?

Comment: В смысле? Можете показать пример кода, как вы пишите? Вы же можете в DAL определить класс, а потом наследоваться от него и в аттрибутах Metadata указывать такие, какие нужны в конкретной сборке вам.

Comment: как-то путано я описал проблему, вопрос был в следующем, как правильно раскидать все это, в dal только edmx а в ui/bll класс с метаданными и ресурсами или метаданные поместить с bll, но тогда как метаданные связать с ресурсами. а если мета.. в ui/bll поместить то они не привязываются к классам таблиц в dal

Comment: поправьте просто вопрос, чтобы точнее проблему обрисовать. Но в целом, зачем метаданные с ресурсами в DAL?

Comment: тогда они в разный неймспейсах будут, не заработает привязка для метаданных